# Angularjs & grunt: Injecting a remote javascript file

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, inject, wiredep, grunt-wiredep

We are using wiredep to inject javascript files into the project. Is there a way to inject remote files using wiredep/grunt? I looked for documentation, but could not find any.